# Response.Redirect not sending string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i've got a bit of a problem trying to set up a general error page in MVC.

I am handling all app errors in Global.asax.cs with the following code ->

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (Request.Url.ToString().StartsWith("http://localhost:"))
    //    return;
    string msg;
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("Exception Found");
    sb.AppendLine("Timestamp: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("Error in: " + Request.Url.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("Browser Version: " + Request.UserAgent.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("User IP: " + Request.UserHostAddress.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine("Error Message: " + ex.Message);
    sb.AppendLine("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
    msg = sb.ToString();
    Server.ClearError();
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Error/Error?w={0}", msg ));
}
```

My problem is that i'm not getting a redirect. I see the same page URL and a blank page when i'm creating an error.

If i remove "errorMsg" and add a SIMPLE STRING, it works, redirects with the required param. Ex:

```
string test = "testme";
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Error/Error?w={0}", test));
```

That does redirect me to the error page with param "testme". What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Most likely, the redirect is failing because your query param exceeds 2083 chars, which is the total limit that the browser will accept as a URI.

Comment: The error information needs to be escaped correctly. You should not be outputting such specific error details to users. A malicious user could use that information to their advantage. I would suggest that you log the error information on the server and redirect the user to a more general error page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You to need escape all the parameters (UrlEncode). At the moment it is unescaped and has a whole bunch of new lines too.

Before you do that, I suggest you just append "hello world" parameter and re-display that to ensure your redirect page is working

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Now i gotta make that query shorter. Any tip on another way to send error information to that page instead of query string?